# Persist Custom ID Attributes in Quilljs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-quill

We need to persist ID attributes for every div that we create on a new line.
We tried saving quill delta in the localstorage and when tried to set using setContents() the IDs are changed. When we try to insert a new Delta or text it is creating new random IDs.

```js
import Quill from 'quill';
import {v4 as UUID4} from 'uuid';
const Parchment = Quill.import('parchment');
const IDAttribute = new Parchment.Attributor.Attribute('id-attribute', 'id', {
  scope: Parchment.Scope.BLOCK,
});
Quill.register(
  {
    'attributors/attribute/id': IDAttribute,
  },
  true
);

Quill.register(
  {
    'formats/id': IDAttribute,
  },
  true
);

const Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
const Delta = Quill.import('delta');
Block.tagName = 'p';
Quill.register(Block, true);
class BlockBlot extends Block {
  constructor(domNode) {
    super(domNode);
    domNode.setAttribute('id', UUID4());
    console.log(Delta(BlockBlot))
    this.cache = {};
  }
}

BlockBlot.blotName = 'block';

export default BlockBlot;
```

```js
import Block from "./QuillHelpers/test"
Quill.register('formats/block', Block );
```

Is this the correct way to add custom attributes and persist them in quill?

Framework: React 17
react-quill: 1.3.5

Comment: You're just blindly writing to the `id` attribute with a new random ID — shouldn't you be checking if `id` has already been set before attempting to overwrite it?

Comment: Thanks Alec, for your response I have resolved the issue by checking deltas which have attributes and then assigned random ids which don't have one.